# monotone functions agreeing with Holder functions on a large set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, monotone-functions, bounded-variation, holder-spaces

Let $\alpha \in (0,1)$, $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous monotone function and $\varepsilon>0$. Does there exist a function $\phi_{\varepsilon} \in \mathcal{C}^{\alpha}$ such that $\lambda(\{t \in [0,1]: f(t)=\phi_{\varepsilon}(t)\})\geqslant 1-\varepsilon$?

Ideas: A monotone continuous function is a.e. differentiable and therefore by regularity of the Lebesgue measure we can find an arbitrarily small open set that includes all the points where the function is not differentiable. Then one can write this open set as a countable disjoint union of open sets, on which we could "smoothly interpolate". Then we have a function that is smooth on this open set, but I don't know how to ensure regularity on the whole interval...

The prototype of a counterexample, the Cantor-function, does not work as we can take an approximation with Lipschitz-functions agreeing up to small measure with the Cantor-function. Maybe the "fat-Cantor-function" could be an idea of a counterexample.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: [This google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22typical+monotone%22+%22function%22+%22category%22) might be relevant.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thank you for the answer, I was not aware of this paper. It seems related, but I cannot deduce an answer to my question from the results in there

Comment: I wasn't sure whether it could be used to answered your question, which is why I said "might be relevant". But it might lead you to other papers that could be of use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can actually find a Lipschitz continuous function. Take a look at this post [BV](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/328207/lusin-lipschitz-approximation-in-bv-and-sobolev-space?rq=1). The proof is not easy though but this is because it is for functions of several variables. There should be a simpler proof in the one dimensional case.